# Box positioning with/without flex

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I saved the code here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FxKHB
Maybe it's better for you to see it and try something to help me.

My problem is that I have to position the box with 'Dessert' just under the box with 'Entrée' : without the space between.

I use flexbox layout in my container :

```
.menuContainer
{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Problem : the box 'Dessert' is pushed under because there is too much lines in the box 'Plat'.

Maybe I chose the wrong layout. I chose this one because when the width of the window/device is too small, I need to get everything in one column.
I can not just change the relative position of my box because each content is not static. I mean, it can have more lines.

What should I do ? Is it even possible ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *elegant* alternative would be to change your `align-items` property to `stretch` for you container and then vertically center the items by making them flexboxes.

I guess it is not quite the desired effect, but without changing the markup this is the best solution I could come up with.

[PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AftCk)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Indeed, it's elegant but not perfect. In the pen, I added some border but the final result is without. Maybe I have to completely change the layout and just do two columns but It's not easy to make the responsive after this because it's not only one column after the other.

Comment: similDo you mean on the pen I added? I see a 1px solid #FF594E border. I had a similar problem a while ago, ended up using my solution to be able to get the good responsive layout. If you really wanted to you could change the entire layout depending on the viewport, but that's another story :)

Comment: "Change the layout depending on the viewport" Mhh that's not bad I think ! I'll try.

Thank you !

Comment: You should be able to solve your problem that way, but remember that if you create two different layouts and hide one with a media query, you will load twice as much content, hence slower pageload!

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought during my try. Finally, I decided to do it with only two simple columns and reverse 'Plat' and 'Dessert' to get good order when everything is in one column.
http://codepen.io/Rictus/pen/uqyDK
I think it's better. When we have two collumns, it's doesn't really matter that 'Dessert' is after 'Plat' because we can see everything.

Comment: Had I not been french too I'd probably not have understood what you meant about the order! Be careful though, on your new pen your `li` get larger than you `*Column` containers on small devices.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, I'm french and I'm writing reall fast without thinking if you can understand. Sorry again !
Yes it's larger but I just fix it in the project (not in the pen). Now, you can change the width of your window, you'll never se a horizontal scroll bar ! :)